# int(4) it must be of type list tuple or dict

Tags: python, mysql, discord, pycord

I am creating an discord command called bancheck. The command takes an banid which is an integer stored in an mysql database. I then fetch the user_id and reason from the tables bans where the ban_id is. I then execute that but receive the error.
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: int(4), it must be of type list, tuple or dict`

CODE:

```
    @commands.slash_command(name="bancheck", description="Checks the database for an ban.")
    async def bancheck(self, ctx, ban_id: int):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=config.host,
            user=config.user,
            password=config.password,
            database=config.database        
            )

        mycursor = mydb.cursor()

        sql = "SELECT user_id, reason FROM bans WHERE ban_id = %s"
        val = (ban_id)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        result = mycursor.fetchone()

        if result:
            user_id, reason = result
            message = f"The user with ID {user_id} was banned for '{reason}'"
        else:
            message = "No ban was found with that ID."

        embed = discord.Embed(title="Ban Check", description=message, color=discord.Color.red())
        embed.add_field(name="Ban ID", value=f"{ban_id}", inline=False)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed)

        mydb.close()
```

The error occurs on line 63 code `mycursor.execute(sql, val)`

Here is the table structure, the ban_id is an auto increment value.

[image: table structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is as described; your `val` needs to be a [tuple, list, or dictionary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html). Wrapping a value in parethenses by itself won't make it a tuple - gotta chuck a comma in there as well. Without it, the parentheses get removed and it's interpreted as a single value rather than a sequence.

```py
val = (ban_id, )  # will be interpreted as a tuple
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

Example in an ipython terminal:

[image: example]